# Testcase fails when running as a Jenkins project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, jenkins

I have a simple test case where it asserts the Width and Height of an element.

```
Assert.AreEqual(Height, 170, 100);
Assert.AreEqual(Width, 636, 100);
```

The test case passes when it runs using VS test explorer.
But when I create a project and run it using Jenkins project, the above test case fails every time.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Did you try to capture the screen shot on fail and look what is actually shown in the browser?

Comment: hmmm... Good idea.Let me try.

Answer (score 1):

The test might fail due to screen size difference.

Firstly, you may try resizing your browser with given numbers to make sure that Jenkins Server has the same Dimension as your local machine.

Something like;

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(450,600); 
driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension);
```

and then;

```
Assert.AreEqual(Height, 170, 100);
Assert.AreEqual(Width, 636, 100);
```

Comment: IMO, it is always a better practice to ensure that the Window dimensions are the same for all the tests.

Answer (score -1):

When you are running it through Jenkins, it execute in the background and doesn't get a window. So, it will not have height and width.

Comment: This is not true. Jenkins just runs a command line. It can easily start the tests in UI session.

Comment: When you login to your machine, do you see the UI?

Comment: If you have installed Jenkins as a service, it will be installed as an administrator user, so all your execution happens through that user. So, you have to login to the machine using that user's credentials to see the execution.

Comment: Sorry Mayur, but I'm 100% confident that it's possible to have Jenkins execute a command to run the browser with a window. There's nothing magical about a service that prevents windows from spawning.

Comment: Okay. I would like to see what it is when you resolved it.

Comment: @ Mayur Shah  no , i didnt see any UI